# Spock with Spring-boot stubbing doesn't work correctly

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, spock

I would like to write spock unit test in spring boot project. When I'm trying to stub repository it doesn/t work correctly.

I debug it and in the test method the stub looks correct, return expected result. But when we call method on the service class  `eventMemberService.eventMembers` it's return "real" data not from the stub... What is wrong with it ?

```
import com.ostrouchprzemyslaw.willyoube.repositories.EventMemberRepository
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest
import spock.lang.Shared
import spock.lang.Specification

@SpringBootTest
class EventMemberServiceImplTest extends Specification {

    @Shared
    EventMember eventMember

    @Autowired
    EventMemberService eventMemberService

    EventMemberRepository eventMemberRepository = Stub(EventMemberRepository.class)

    def setupSpec(){
        eventMember = new EventMember()
        eventMember.firstName = 'Przemek'
        eventMember.lastName = 'Ostrouch'
        eventMember.email = 'przemek@gmail.com'
    }

    def "When call getEventMembers it list all members"() {

        given:
        def mockListOfMembers = new ArrayList<EventMember>()
        mockListOfMembers.add(eventMember)

        when:
        eventMemberRepository.findAll() >> mockListOfMembers
        def result = eventMemberService.eventMembers

        then:
        result == mockListOfMembers
    }
```

```
public class EventMemberServiceImpl implements EventMemberService {

    private EventMemberRepository eventMemberRepository;

    public EventMemberServiceImpl(EventMemberRepository eventMemberRepository) {
        this.eventMemberRepository = eventMemberRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public List<EventMember> getEventMembers() {
        List<EventMember> returnList = new ArrayList<>();
        eventMemberRepository.findAll().forEach(returnList::add);
        return returnList;
    }

Expected result: eventMemberService.eventMembers will return list with one eventMember, but actual result is empty list (there are no any data in DB)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EventMemberService` is not a mock, what are you expecting? Maybe you forgot to inject your repository stub into that service. If you do that, it should work. ;-)

Comment: Yes, of course, stupid fault. I forgot "inject" stubbed repository to the service... I tried to test `EventMemberService` I shouldn't @Autowire it, just create by new and add this repository by the constructor.